# Can't connect to mongodb docker container from another container

Tags: mongodb, docker, pymongo, docker-compose

I have the following simplified design: a mongodb container and a "python-client" docker container, that is linked to the former. This is my simplified `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
mongodb:
  build: "mongodb"
  dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
  hostname: "mongodb.local"
  ports:
  - "27017:27017"

client:
  build: "client"
  dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
  hostname: "client.local"
  links:
  - "mongodb:mongodb"
  environment:
  - "MONGODB_URL=mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/admin"
  - "MONGODB_DB=historictraffic"
```

I'm able to establish a successful connection using `pymongo` from my host using the `mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/admin` connection string (pay attention to `localhost`):

```
$ ipython
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/admin')
db = mongo.test
col = db.test
col.insert_one({'x': 1})
# This works
```

But I can't connect from the client container. Apparently the link is correct:

```
 / # cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.27     client.local client
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.26     historictraffic_mongodb_1 mongodb
172.17.0.26     mongodb mongodb historictraffic_mongodb_1
172.17.0.26     mongodb_1 mongodb historictraffic_mongodb_1
```

But when I do the same test, it fails:

```
/ # ipython
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/admin')
db = mongo.test
col = db.test
col.insert_one({'x': 2})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ServerSelectionTimeoutError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c5d62e5590d5> in <module>()
----> 1 col.insert_one({'x': 2})

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.pyc in insert_one(self, document)
    464         if "_id" not in document:
    465             document["_id"] = ObjectId()
--> 466         with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
    467             return InsertOneResult(self._insert(sock_info, document),
    468                                    self.write_concern.acknowledged)

/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.pyc in __enter__(self)
     15     def __enter__(self):
     16         try:
---> 17             return self.gen.next()
     18         except StopIteration:
     19             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield")

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.pyc in _get_socket(self, selector)
    661     @contextlib.contextmanager
    662     def _get_socket(self, selector):
--> 663         server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
    664         try:
    665             with server.get_socket(self.__all_credentials) as sock_info:

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.pyc in select_server(self, selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
    119         return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
    120                                                  server_selection_timeout,
--> 121                                                  address))
    122 
    123     def select_server_by_address(self, address,

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.pyc in select_servers(self, selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
     95                 if server_timeout == 0 or now > end_time:
     96                     raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
---> 97                         self._error_message(selector))
     98 
     99                 self._ensure_opened()

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb:27017: [Errno 113] Host is unreachable
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue...

Answer (score 0):

This failure is probably because mongo hasn't started up yet. You can retry the connection with a short delay between retries, and it should work after one or two attempts.

Comment: Hi @dnephin, I tried several times without success, even after several minutes. mongo is fully started because I can connect to it from my host (using `localhost`).